# Updating predefined value into mysql database if form is submitted with empty fields

Tags: php, mysql, forms

the syntax

```
$default_message = "No food name entered";
    if(isset($_POST['food_name']) && !empty($_POST['food_name'])){  
       echo $_POST['$dafult_message'];
    }
```

should check if the field `food_name` is null or empty in database and attempt to insert predefined value `No food name entered` into database when the following form is updated with empty field but unfortunately it doesn't update the predefined value. i can't see anything illogical in it. any idea?

---

```
if ((isset($_POST["MM_update"])) && ($_POST["MM_update"] == "formX")) { 

    $default_message = "No food name entered";
    if(isset($_POST['food_name']) && !empty($_POST['food_name'])){  
       echo $_POST['$dafult_message'];
    }

$updateSQL = sprintf("UPDATE foodtable SET food_name=%s WHERE food_id=%s",    
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['food_name'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['food_id'], "int"));

  mysql_select_db($database_XYZ, $XYZ);
  $Result1 = mysql_query($updateSQL, $XYZ) or die(mysql_error());

  $updateGoTo = "choicefood.php";
  if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
    $updateGoTo .= (strpos($updateGoTo, '?')) ? "&" : "?";
    $updateGoTo .= $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
      }
  header(sprintf("Location: %s", $updateGoTo));
    exit ();
}
```

---

```
<form action="<?php echo $editFormAction; ?>" method="post" name="formX" id="formX">
<table align="center">
  <tr valign="baseline">
    <td align="right" nowrap="nowrap">Update Food Name:</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="food_name" value="" size="32" /></td>
  </tr>
   <tr valign="baseline">
    <td nowrap="nowrap" align="right">
     <input type="hidden" name="MM_update" value="formX" />
      <input type="hidden" name="food_id" value="<?php echo $query['food_id']; ?>" />
     </td>
                    <td>
                    <input type="submit" value="Update Food Name" />
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
              </form>
```

---

thanks,

Comment: You're taking data from the POST values sent to the form and pushing them into a string, a practice that leaves you vulnerable to SQL injection. Please use binding instead.

Comment: can you give me an example?

Comment: Sure. If someone posts "food_name" with a value of "''; DROP TABLE Foodtable; --", then you'll lose your table.

Comment: this is a great piece of information, thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
    $default_message = "No food name entered";

    if ( @$_POST['food_name'] == '' ) {

        $_POST['food_name'] = $default_message;

    }

    echo '<p>', $_POST['food_name'], '</p>;
```

Comment: `echo '<p>', $_POST['food_name'], '</p>;` is a new concept to me. this info shall be updated in database. why this tag for then? thanks,

Comment: Is just an echo, for debugging or just to display it on screen. The database part comes bellow, and the variable is already set at this point.

Comment: the syntax can only update the value of `$default_message` but it is unable to update the field values of form inputted by the users manually. what's going wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work as you intend, but you've misspelled `"$default_message"` in this line of code:

```
echo $_POST['$dafult_message'];
```

Comment: it was a slip of key stroke. may be i should wait until the server updates the syntax.